# Как сохранить 100% качество картинки

Tags: javascript, html, css, img

Есть картинка, которая когда вставляю на сайт, теряет качество при адаптиве. Ниже приведен пример как я вставляю на сайт (через css вставлял и тоже ничего не помогает). Так же пробовал через object-fit: none, это помогает, но почему-то когда захожу через ноут, качество плохое, а через ПК хорошее. Нужно сохранить максимальное качество. Картинка сама по себе отличного качества
1-картинка: С object-fit:none
2-картинка: Без object-fit:none
3-картинка: Исходник

```css
div {
  max-width: 500px
  max-height: 300px
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img>
 </div>
```

[image: c object-fit:none]

[image: без object-fit:none]

[image: Исходник]

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Какая картинка? Что такое «хорошее» и «плохое» качество? Вы уверены, что у вас на ноутбуке не накручен масштаб например?

Comment: Исходная картинка - это хорошее качество. При загрузке ее на сайт, качество ухудшается. Нет, не накручен

Comment: Всё ещё ничего не понятно. Приложите картинку, составьте [mcve], покажите скриншоты «хорошего» и «плохого» качества с действующим object-fit:none

Comment: Все, добавил. 1-картинка: С object-fit:none 2-картинка: Без object-fit:none 3-картинка: Исходник

Comment: И вообще хотелось бы еще узнать, какие есть способы, чтобы сохранить максимально хорошее качество картинки при загрузке на сайт

Comment: Сайт на CMS или что это за абстрактный сайт, куда Вы каким-то образом загружаете картинку? Если это CMS, то при загрузке могут создаваться миниатюры изображения и тд. Если Вы просто закидываете файлы на севрвер и выводите её в html, то на качество это никак не влияет.

Comment: Возможно я не так сказал. Под ( куда Вы каким-то образом загружаете картинку) я имею ввиду, что вставляю путь картинки в HTML

Comment: На вашем скриншоте «1-картинка: С object-fit:none» с качеством всё в порядке. В чём проблема-то?

Comment: Это фото с ПК, но на ноуте почему-то оно плохое.

Comment: Значит сделайте скриншот на ноуте, а то до сих пор ничего не понятно

Comment: Когда картинка изменяется в размерах, то её качество всегда хуже просто потому, что она теряет часть данных или ей неоткуда их получить. Чтобы картинка не теряла качество, она должны быть строго того же размера, и должна находиться строго в тех же пикселях экрана. У вас картинка может стоять чуть в другом месте или быть меньше-больше. Как вариант можно делать исходную картинку раза в три больше, чтобы у браузера было больше данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала уберите ошибки в css расставьте точки с запятой.

1. Для того чтобы изображение хорошего качества вам нужно **сделать изображение хорошего качества**
2. Если вы хотите использовать `object-fit` то почитайте [это](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)
3. Возможно вы работаете в СMS например как WordPress или Bitrix или что подобное. В этом случи проверьте настройки и посмотрите через инспектор какие стили вешаются на изображение.
4. Не используйте `height: 100%;`, напишите лучше `height: auto;` Может разницы нету, но по моему мнению такая запись более верная.
5. Еще раз проверьте название классов, тегов к которым вы хотите применить стили.
6. Иногда помогает `image-rendering: pixelated;`
7. Используйте векторные изображения или изображения в формате webP